# Apache Problems

Tags: apache, wampserver

I'm trying to start apache in Wampserver.

The icon stays orange even though:

```
I have terminated skype, 
port forwarded port 80, 
the service is installed, 
port 80 is open and is not being used by any program or service 
and i've set the ip for listening to: 0.0.0.0:80
```

What can be the problem?

Thanks! P.S It worked before but now, it don't. I have not made any changes since then.

Comment: This seems to be off-topic for SO! Please post your question on http://serverfault.com/!

Comment: Look in the `apache error log` ( get to it using the menus on wampmanager ). Also check the `Windows Event Viewer` for messages from Apache.